# Difference between running docker and docker compose

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am working with an docker image **nanoninja/php-fpm:8.1**.
When I run the image manually, the PHP works.

```
docker container run --rm --name phpfpm -v $(pwd):/var/www/html -p 3000:3000 nanoninja/php-fpm php -S="0.0.0.0:3000" -t="/var/www/html"
```

[image]

But when I try to run the same image with **docker-compose.yml** file, I don't get a connection to PHP.
Here is my very simple **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    php:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm:8.1
        restart: always
        ports:
           - 3000:9000
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

I'm **not** using a **Dockerfile**.

Question: How to run **PHP** without **Nginx** using **only** **docker-compose.yml** file?

Image link: https://github.com/nanoninja/php-fpm

Comment: In your manual command you map port 3000 on the local host to port 3000 on the container, in your compose file you map the local port 3000 to port 9000 in the contianer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker-compose file equivalent to your `docker container run` command would be something like

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    image: nanoninja/php-fpm:8.1
    container_name: phpfpm
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: php -S="0.0.0.0:3000" -t="/var/www/html"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

The `-v` option becomes the `volumes:` section. The part after the image name becomes the `command:`. The `-p` option becomes the `ports:` section. `--name` becomes `container_name:`, etc.